# django queryset F get last

Tags: django, django-queryset

django 2.0.2 python 3.4

models.py

```
Post(models.Model):
   Id = pk
   content = text

Reply(models.Model):
   Id = pk
   PostId = Fk(Post)
   content = text
```

view.py

```
Post.objects.all().annotate(lastreply=F("Reply__content__last"))
```

can use last query in F() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `latest` cannot be used with `F()`.

One possible solution is including a timestamp in the `reply` class

```
Post(models.Model):
   Id = pk
   content = text

Reply(models.Model):
   Id = pk
   PostId = Fk(Post)
   content = text
   timestamp = DateTime(auto)
```

Then you can use a query of this format to get the latest reply for each post.
`Reply.objects.annotate(max_time=Max('Post__Reply__timestamp')).filter(timestamp=F('max_time'))`

Please note that this is really time consuming for large number of records.
If you are using a Postgres DB you can use `distinct()`

`Reply.objects.order_by('Post__Id','-timestamp').distinct('Post__Id')`

Comment: can't Get ReplyContent in Max("Post__Reply__timestamp") ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a small mistake in the query. The query should be done with ```Reply``` objects not ```Post```. I've made the correction.

Answer (score 0):

F expression has no way to do that.
but Django has another way to handle it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

for this problem, the code below can solve this:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

sub_qs = Reply.objects.filter(
    PostId=OuterRef('pk')
).order_by('timestamp')

qs = Post.objects.annotate(
    last_reply_content=Subquery(
        sub_qs.values('content')[:1]))
```

### how does it work?

sub_qs is the related model queryset, where you want to take only the last reply for each post, to do that, we use the OuterRef, it will take care to get replies related to this post, and finally the order_by that will order by the timestamp, the first is the most recent, and the last is the eldest.

```
sub_qs = Reply.objects.filter(
    PostId=OuterRef('pk')
).order_by('timestamp')
```

the second part is the Post queryset with a annotate, we wanna apply the sub_qs in an extra field, and using subquery will allow us to insert another queryset inside of annotate

we use .values('content') to get only the content field, and slice the sub_qs with [:1] to get only the first occurrence.

```
qs = Post.objects.annotate(
    last_reply_content=Subquery(
        sub_qs.values('content')[:1]))
```